# How can I create a UV map of my arm?

Tags: 3d, 3d-modelling, uv-mapping

I want to design a custom sleeve tattoo based on the actual dimensions of my arm. Any suggestions on the best way to go about this?

I am a bit of a 3D noob but my idea was to scan my arm with a kinect, create a mesh, and create a UV map from the mesh in PS. I think this is the correct workflow but I'm not sure exactly how to go about each step. My main problem is just getting a UV map from a mesh. Once I have the UV map I should be fine.

Can anyone recommend the best workflow and software tools I might need for each step?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

The hard part is the reconstruction of the arm. Check this [paper](http://rogerioferis.com/VisualRecognitionAndSearch/material/Class9Kinect1.pdf).

If you manage to get good samples on the arm with a relatively good density, you can try this great [tool](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/powercrust.html) (check the associated paper).

Once you have a mesh use [Graphite](http://alice.loria.fr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22) or Blender to improve the sampling, the mesh and get a nice uv map